# fstream seekp() not working when the file is opened in ios::in and out mode

Tags: c++

I want to replace some certain portion (in the middle) in a binary file. If I use `ostream out("file.bin",ios::binary)` ,it will delete the old file and creat a new one. But if I use `fstream out("file.bin",ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out)` ,`seekp()` will not go to the right place and `tellp()` always return -1. So is there any way to replace some certain portion in a file?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it should be OK to seek to a specific position in the file. You might want to make sure that the file uses the C locale (`std::locale::classic()`) before opening it, though: seeking with some fancy encodings won't work and the use of `std::ios_base::binary` doesn't inhibit code conversions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must open the stream with the *at the end*, *in* and *out* bits set:

```
std::fstream out("file.bin", ios::binary | ios_base::ate);
```

This will prevent your file to be *reset* at opening; then, using `seekp` and [*unformatted output*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) functions you will be able to edit it in the middle.

---

This example outputs `stackovstrlow`, showing how to chain all steps together:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // create the bin file
    {
        std::string str("stackoverflow\n");
        std::ofstream file("file.bin", std::ios_base::binary);
        file.write(str.c_str(), str.length() + 1);
    }
    // edit the bin file "in the middle"
    {
        std::fstream file("file.bin", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::ate);
        file.seekp(7);
        file.write("str", 3);
    }
    // read and see what we've done
    std::ifstream file("file.bin", std::ios_base::binary);
    std::vector<char> v(14);
    file.read(v.data(), 14);
    std::string str(v.cbegin(), v.cend());
    std::cout << str;
}
```

Comment: The C `open()` API was certainly clearer, with `O_TRUNC` and whatnot.  :)

Comment: @JohnZwinck I'm not a fan of C++ streams to write binary files, I think they were built with other use cases in mind :)

Comment: How exactly does `std::ios_base::app` help to replace "some certain portion(**in the middle**)"?

Comment: No, still wrong. `app` means all writes occur at the end. You probably meant `ate`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, I meant app, but I looking a the documentation, I guess I was wrong...

Comment: Thank you all. `fstream out("file.bin",ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out|ios::ate)` finally worked.

Answer (score 2):

Seeking on file streams is supposed to work although not always. Notably, seeking does fail if the encoding used by the `imbue()`ed `std::locale()` is variable width. Quoting from 27.9.1.5 [filebuf.virtuals] paragraph 13:

> *Effects*: Let `width` denote `a_codecvt.encoding()`. If `is_open() == false`, or `off != 0 && width <= 0`, then the positioning operation fails. ...

Assuming the file was opened OK, it would imply a `std::locale` with a non-fixed width encoding was used. The approach to avoid this issue is to use the C-locale before opening the file. For example:

```
std::fstream stream;
stream.imbue(std::locale::classic());
stream.open("file.bin", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
```